# Desktop in top left corner of monitor

Tags: .desktop

i've not been using Ubuntu long but am slowly getting the hang of things, i rebooted a while ago and now the desktop is all messed up, its stuck in the top corner of my monitor, and i have no idea how to fix it, does anyone know what to do?
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you been playing around with the display settings try if so or if not try working with the resolution of you displays as well as other aspects in display settings

to access open up settings and go to displays if not i don't know what to say you should have made a backup so that if something like this happens you can restore your computer to where it was in the previous backup

the only other thing i can think of is to try and open a terminal via [ctrl]+[alt]+[t]
and enter the fallowing command

```
unity --reset
```

or

```
sudo unity --reset
```

this should reset your desktop to where it was when you first installed Linux this may work if you dont have a backup but i'm not guaranteeing it

Comment: thanks for the help, sudo unity --reset worked, now to make a backup

Comment: From 14.04 ERROR: the reset option is now deprecated